# how to align text and icon left on MaterialButton (with icon directly after text)?

Tags: android, material-components-android

I want to create Button with text and Icon, both left-aligned.
I am using  `app:iconGravity="textEnd"` to place the icon directly after the button-text, but the icon stays in old centered position if I change text positioning to left by using `android:gravity="left"`

[image]

my layout-xml:

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/listentry_button"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Icon"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_arrow_straight_right"
        app:iconGravity="textEnd"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="@string/account_data_personal_data"
        android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
        app:iconTint="@color/secondaryColor"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

any idea how to achieve this with material-button or is is it impossible?

Comment: Why not try using linear layout instead of Material button ?

Answer (score 4):

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="My button"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_arrow"
            app:iconGravity="textEnd"
            />
```

above code can give you the following result

[image]

OR

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="My button"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_arrow"
            app:iconGravity="textStart"
            />
```

above code can give you the following result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you try changing the layout width to wrap content?

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Comment: ok, then it would work, thank you. but I want to fill the whole avallable width with the button (because of its click-listener), so I can't use this solution. I guess I have to create layout with textView and image to solve this.

Comment: You can try center the text in your button.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

it works for me.